# replace the assigned number in increasing order

Tags: bash, perl, awk

I have file containing following format. In the following file I want to replace every `t=0.00000` with `t=0.00000+50` like 50.00000 without changing the format of file. my file looks like:

```
MODULE  for the   Modulate t=   0.00000

MODULE  for the    Modulate t=   4.00000

MODULE   overshoot  Modulate t=   8.00000

MODULE   fail for  Modulate t=  12.00000

MODULE   successful for the Modulate t=  16.00000
```

I did something like this but not able to increment and its taking much time manually.

```
sed -i 's/MODULE  for the   Modulate t=   0.00000/MODULE  for the   Modulate t=50 /g'  file.txt
```

expected output:

```
MODULE  for the  Modulate t=   50.00000

MODULE  for the  Modulate t=  54.00000

MODULE  overshoot   Modulate t=  58.00000

MODULE   fail for  Modulate t=  62.00000

MODULE   successful for the Modulate t=  66.00000
```

Comment: Show expected output for input

Comment: Put it in your question formatted.

Comment: I'm assuming that the first number should have changed to 50.00000 ?

Comment: regular expressions suffer from being unable to 'understand' numbers - they're all about string patterns - even the ones that happen to contain digits.

Answer (score 4):

In a Perl one-line command

```
perl -pe 's/Modulate\s+t=\K\s*([0-9.]+)/sprintf '%10.5f',$1+50/e' my_file
```

#### output

```
MODULE  for the   Modulate t=  50.00000
MODULE  for the    Modulate t=  54.00000
MODULE   overshoot  Modulate t=  58.00000
MODULE   fail for  Modulate t=  62.00000
MODULE   successful for the Modulate t=  66.00000
```

Answer (score 2):

Using awk

```
awk 'NF{$NF=sprintf("%.5f",$NF+50)}1' file

MODULE  for the  Modulate t=   50.00000

MODULE  for the  Modulate t=  54.00000

MODULE  overshoot   Modulate t=  58.00000

MODULE   fail for  Modulate t=  62.00000

MODULE   successful for the Modulate t=  66.00000
```

Answer (score 0):

**incremental**

```
awk '/t=[[:blank:]]*0.00000/{gsub(/t=[[:blank:]]*0.00000/, "t= " (Inc+=50) ".00000")}1' YourFile > NewFile
```

you can add `BEGIN{Inc=-50}` as first action if first occurence of t=0 need to still be 0

**decal**

```
sed '/\(t=[[:blank:]]*\)0\([.]00000\)/ s//\150\2/' YourFile > NewFile
```

Comment: But is is not working for me in loop. The same answer i got using sed . I would like to replace 4 8 12 ...... n increament by 50

Comment: maybe a little sample of expected result will help to understand exact need

Comment: MODULE     Modulate t=   50.00000

MODULE     Modulate t=   54.00000

MODULE     Modulate t=   58.00000  and so on

Comment: @123 make it simple and efficient